# Python generic type wrapper

Tags: python

I am assuming this question has been asked a million times already but I can't seem to make sense of a few things so please bear with me here. I am trying to make do generic inheritance in Python. This is what I want to accomplish: I have a method that takes in a generic type and it returns a class that has been inherited from that parent class

this is what the code looks like

```
def make_foo(parent):
    class Relationship(parent):
        # def __init__(self):

        @staticmethod
        def should_see_this_method(self):
            print("Hello here")
            return True

    return Relationship
```

Now this is the piece of code I am have

```
NewType = make_relationship(str)
another_test: NewType = "Hello"
another_test.should_see_this_method()
another_test.capitalize()
```

Now I am getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'should_see_this_method'`

I am not sure if this is anti pattern or not but I am just curios to know how I can do this.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```py
another_test: NewType = "Hello"
```

doesn't do what you think it does.

This is a *type hint*. Hints are used by static type checkers, linters, and the like to check if your code has obvious bugs or is being used incorrectly. It helps you at "compile time" to catch things that are possible sources of errors, but it has *no impact* on the *runtime* behavior of the code.

Importantly, *it does not construct an object of type `NewType`*. It constructs a `str`. You can see this easily by calling `type(another_test)`, which indicates this is a `str`. (It's also in the message of the `AttributeError` in your question.)

To actually construct that object, you have to do the usual thing:

```py
>>> another_test = NewType("Hello")
>>> isinstance(another_test, NewType)
True
```

---

An unrelated problem in your code: `staticmethod`s should not take `self` as the first argument. They are not bound to any instance. You'll see an error once you actually get to the line which calls the method.